# Let $ w $ be a solution to $A^T Ax = A^Tb $. Which of the following statement is false?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, least-squares

Let $ w $ be a solution to $A^T Ax = A^Tb $. Which of the following statement is false?

$\quad $  (1) $ Aw - b $ is orthogonal to the column space of A.

$\quad $  (2) For any vector $ v \in R^n, ||Aw - b|| <= || Av - b|| $

$\quad $  (3) $ w $ is a least square solution to Ax = b, which always exists

$\quad $  (4) $  w $ must be the unique solution to $ A^TAx = A^Tb $

**(4) is false,** because the columns of A need to be linearly independent for w to be the only solution. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It is correct. If the columns of $A$ are dependent (this is called multicollinearity) then $A^TA$ is singular and your system has a whole affine subspace of solutions $x$. However, the vector $Ax$ is unique,. being the projection of $A^Tb$ onto the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$A^T Aw = A^Tb$ $\Rightarrow$ $A^T(Aw-b)=0$

Let $A_1,...,A_n$ be columns of A, according to definition of transpose and matrix multiplication

$A^T(Aw-b)=\begin{pmatrix} <A_1,Aw,b> \\ \vdots  \\ <A_n,Aw-b> \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$<c_1A_1+...+c_nA_n,Aw-b>=c_1<A_1,Aw-b>+...+c_n<A_n,Aw-b>=0$